# react-native-image-crop-picker call to openCropper causes crash on ios only

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm trying to implement react-native-image-crop-picker into a react-native app. Everything works fine on Android, it's just ios that causes the problem. I narrowed it down to the openCropper method. I was able to fix part of the problem, but I'm stuck on the last little bit.

The code inside of react-native that I'm using is:

```
ImagePicker.openPicker({
  mediaType: 'photo',
  writeTempFile: true,
  includeExif: true,
})
  .then(image => {
    this.setState({ modalOpen: false });
    console.log('returned from openPicker');
    // Remove the Promise All for the ImagePicker
    ImagePicker.openCropper({
      path: (image as PickerImage).path,
      width: 400,
      height: 400,
      writeTempFile: false,
      includeExif: true
    })
      .then(croppedImage => {
        console.log('returned from openCropper');

      })
      .catch(e => { console.log('Error in openCropper: ' + e) });
  })
  .catch(e => { console.log('Error in openPicker: ' + e) });
```

The first issue I had was an exception in the ImageCropPicker.m file. The exception I got was:

```
2020-01-16 20:02:30.801198-0600 PolyAmDate[58570:2930766] [core] "Error returned from daemon: Error Domain=com.apple.accounts Code=7 "(null)""
2020-01-16 20:02:38.134199-0600 PolyAmDate[58570:2930766] id: 744BEFC9-7B2C-4103-A7EE-9B4FD80FE700/L0/001 filename: IMG_0005.HEIC
2020-01-16 20:02:39.144 [info][tid:com.apple.root.default-qos][RCTImageLoader.mm:738] [PERF ASSETS] Loading image at size {3024, 4032}, which is larger than the screen size {750, 1334}
2020-01-16 20:02:39.147 [info][tid:com.apple.root.default-qos][RCTImageLoader.mm:738] [PERF ASSETS] Loading image at size {3024, 4032}, which is larger than the screen size {750, 1334}
=================================================================
Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread: -[UIViewController init]
PID: 58570, TID: 2931117, Thread name: (none), Queue name: com.apple.root.default-qos, QoS: 0
Backtrace:
4   PolyAmDate                          0x0000000100ddcf54 -[RSKImageCropViewController init] + 80
5   PolyAmDate                          0x0000000100ddd224 -[RSKImageCropViewController initWithImage:] + 80
6   PolyAmDate                          0x0000000100dacc58 -[ImageCropPicker startCropping:] + 80
7   PolyAmDate                          0x0000000100dacbcc __49-[ImageCropPicker openCropper:resolver:rejecter:]_block_invoke + 280
8   PolyAmDate                          0x0000000100f45960 __119-[RCTImageLoader loadImageWithURLRequest:size:scale:clipped:resizeMode:progressBlock:partialLoadBlock:completionBlock:]_block_invoke_3 + 556
9   PolyAmDate                          0x0000000100f4668c __80-[RCTImageLoader decodeImageData:size:scale:clipped:resizeMode:completionBlock:]_block_invoke_2 + 700
10  PolyAmDate                          0x0000000100f471d8 __80-[RCTImageLoader decodeImageData:size:scale:clipped:resizeMode:completionBlock:]_block_invoke_3.264 + 604
11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001026097fc _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010260abd8 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010260d2d4 _dispatch_queue_override_invoke + 872
14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010261c160 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 376
15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010261ca88 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 156
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001889f6b48 _pthread_wqthread + 212
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001889f9760 start_wqthread + 8
2020-01-16 20:02:39.168687-0600 PolyAmDate[58570:2931117] [reports] Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread: -[UIViewController init]
PID: 58570, TID: 2931117, Thread name: (none), Queue name: com.apple.root.default-qos, QoS: 0
Backtrace:
4   PolyAmDate                          0x0000000100ddcf54 -[RSKImageCropViewController init] + 80
5   PolyAmDate                          0x0000000100ddd224 -[RSKImageCropViewController initWithImage:] + 80
6   PolyAmDate                          0x0000000100dacc58 -[ImageCropPicker startCropping:] + 80
7   PolyAmDate                          0x0000000100dacbcc __49-[ImageCropPicker openCropper:resolver:rejecter:]_block_invoke + 280
8   PolyAmDate                          0x0000000100f45960 __119-[RCTImageLoader loadImageWithURLRequest:size:scale:clipped:resizeMode:progressBlock:partialLoadBlock:completionBlock:]_block_invoke_3 + 556
9   PolyAmDate                          0x0000000100f4668c __80-[RCTImageLoader decodeImageData:size:scale:clipped:resizeMode:completionBlock:]_block_invoke_2 + 700
10  PolyAmDate                          0x0000000100f471d8 __80-[RCTImageLoader decodeImageData:size:scale:clipped:resizeMode:completionBlock:]_block_invoke_3.264 + 604
11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001026097fc _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010260abd8 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010260d2d4 _dispatch_queue_override_invoke + 872
14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010261c160 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 376
15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010261ca88 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 156
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001889f6b48 _pthread_wqthread + 212
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001889f9760 start_wqthread + 8
=================================================================
Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread: -[UIView init]
PID: 58570, TID: 2931117, Thread name: (none), Queue name: com.apple.root.default-qos, QoS: 0
Backtrace:
4   PolyAmDate                          0x0000000100ddeff0 -[RSKImageCropViewController imageScrollView] + 96
5   PolyAmDate                          0x0000000100de1408 -[RSKImageCropViewController setCropMode:] + 112
6   PolyAmDate                          0x0000000100dacd24 -[ImageCropPicker startCropping:] + 284
7   PolyAmDate                          0x0000000100dacbcc __49-[ImageCropPicker openCropper:resolver:rejecter:]_block_invoke + 280
8   PolyAmDate                          0x0000000100f45960 __119-[RCTImageLoader loadImageWithURLRequest:size:scale:clipped:resizeMode:progressBlock:partialLoadBlock:completionBlock:]_block_invoke_3 + 556
9   PolyAmDate                          0x0000000100f4668c __80-[RCTImageLoader decodeImageData:size:scale:clipped:resizeMode:completionBlock:]_block_invoke_2 + 700
10  PolyAmDate                          0x0000000100f471d8 __80-[RCTImageLoader decodeImageData:size:scale:clipped:resizeMode:completionBlock:]_block_invoke_3.264 + 604
11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001026097fc _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010260abd8 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010260d2d4 _dispatch_queue_override_invoke + 872
14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010261c160 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 376
15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010261ca88 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 156
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001889f6b48 _pthread_wqthread + 212
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001889f9760 start_wqthread + 8
2020-01-16 20:02:46.960940-0600 PolyAmDate[58570:2931117] [reports] Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread: -[UIView init]
PID: 58570, TID: 2931117, Thread name: (none), Queue name: com.apple.root.default-qos, QoS: 0
Backtrace:
4   PolyAmDate                          0x0000000100ddeff0 -[RSKImageCropViewController imageScrollView] + 96
5   PolyAmDate                          0x0000000100de1408 -[RSKImageCropViewController setCropMode:] + 112
6   PolyAmDate                          0x0000000100dacd24 -[ImageCropPicker startCropping:] + 284
7   PolyAmDate                          0x0000000100dacbcc __49-[ImageCropPicker openCropper:resolver:rejecter:]_block_invoke + 280
8   PolyAmDate                          0x0000000100f45960 __119-[RCTImageLoader loadImageWithURLRequest:size:scale:clipped:resizeMode:progressBlock:partialLoadBlock:completionBlock:]_block_invoke_3 + 556
9   PolyAmDate                          0x0000000100f4668c __80-[RCTImageLoader decodeImageData:size:scale:clipped:resizeMode:completionBlock:]_block_invoke_2 + 700
10  PolyAmDate                          0x0000000100f471d8 __80-[RCTImageLoader decodeImageData:size:scale:clipped:resizeMode:completionBlock:]_block_invoke_3.264 + 604
11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001026097fc _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010260abd8 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010260d2d4 _dispatch_queue_override_invoke + 872
14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010261c160 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 376
15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010261ca88 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 156
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001889f6b48 _pthread_wqthread + 212
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001889f9760 start_wqthread + 8
=================================================================
Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread: -[UIScrollView initWithFrame:]
PID: 58570, TID: 2931117, Thread name: (none), Queue name: com.apple.root.default-qos, QoS: 0
Backtrace:
4   PolyAmDate                          0x0000000100de68c4 -[RSKImageScrollView initWithFrame:] + 108
5   PolyAmDate                          0x0000000100ddeff0 -[RSKImageCropViewController imageScrollView] + 96
6   PolyAmDate                          0x0000000100de1408 -[RSKImageCropViewController setCropMode:] + 112
7   PolyAmDate                          0x0000000100dacd24 -[ImageCropPicker startCropping:] + 284
8   PolyAmDate                          0x0000000100dacbcc __49-[ImageCropPicker openCropper:resolver:rejecter:]_block_invoke + 280
9   PolyAmDate                          0x0000000100f45960 __119-[RCTImageLoader loadImageWithURLRequest:size:scale:clipped:resizeMode:progressBlock:partialLoadBlock:completionBlock:]_block_invoke_3 + 556
10  PolyAmDate                          0x0000000100f4668c __80-[RCTImageLoader decodeImageData:size:scale:clipped:resizeMode:completionBlock:]_block_invoke_2 + 700
11  PolyAmDate                          0x0000000100f471d8 __80-[RCTImageLoader decodeImageData:size:scale:clipped:resizeMode:completionBlock:]_block_invoke_3.264 + 604
12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001026097fc _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010260abd8 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010260d2d4 _dispatch_queue_override_invoke + 872
15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010261c160 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 376
16  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010261ca88 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 156
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001889f6b48 _pthread_wqthread + 212
18  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001889f9760 start_wqthread + 8
2020-01-16 20:02:47.056606-0600 PolyAmDate[58570:2931117] [reports] Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread: -[UIScrollView initWithFrame:]
PID: 58570, TID: 2931117, Thread name: (none), Queue name: com.apple.root.default-qos, QoS: 0
Backtrace:
4   PolyAmDate                          0x0000000100de68c4 -[RSKImageScrollView initWithFrame:] + 108
5   PolyAmDate                          0x0000000100ddeff0 -[RSKImageCropViewController imageScrollView] + 96
6   PolyAmDate                          0x0000000100de1408 -[RSKImageCropViewController setCropMode:] + 112
7   PolyAmDate                          0x0000000100dacd24 -[ImageCropPicker startCropping:] + 284
8   PolyAmDate                          0x0000000100dacbcc __49-[ImageCropPicker openCropper:resolver:rejecter:]_block_invoke + 280
9   PolyAmDate                          0x0000000100f45960 __119-[RCTImageLoader loadImageWithURLRequest:size:scale:clipped:resizeMode:progressBlock:partialLoadBlock:completionBlock:]_block_invoke_3 + 556
10  PolyAmDate                          0x0000000100f4668c __80-[RCTImageLoader decodeImageData:size:scale:clipped:resizeMode:completionBlock:]_block_invoke_2 + 700
11  PolyAmDate                          0x0000000100f471d8 __80-[RCTImageLoader decodeImageData:size:scale:clipped:resizeMode:completionBlock:]_block_invoke_3.264 + 604
12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001026097fc _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010260abd8 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010260d2d4 _dispatch_queue_override_invoke + 872
15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010261c160 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 376
16  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010261ca88 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 156
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001889f6b48 _pthread_wqthread + 212
18  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001889f9760 start_wqthread + 8
```

Debugging pointed me to the startCropping. The call to initWithImage was causing the error. I enclosed the entire block in a dispatch_async call and that stopped the exception.

However, now what happens is after choosing a file (or taking a picture), I can see it pop up on the screen for just a moment, then it disappears. I'm guessing that it has to do with putting the cropping overlay onto the view, but I can't find that anywhere to test...and it's not throwing an exception.

Answer (score 0):

A little late, but I wanted to put this up in case someone runs into it. The problem was that I was closing the modal in the then function of the openPicker command instead of openCropper. The openCropper function still required it, even though there was no indication that it was needed. Once I moved the setState command to close the modal to the openCropper section, it started working.

```
ImagePicker.openPicker({
  mediaType: 'photo',
  writeTempFile: true,
  includeExif: true,
})
  .then(image => {
    // this.setState({ modalOpen: false }); <-- MOVE THIS...
    console.log('returned from openPicker');
    // Remove the Promise All for the ImagePicker
    ImagePicker.openCropper({
      path: (image as PickerImage).path,
      width: 400,
      height: 400,
      writeTempFile: false,
      includeExif: true
    })
      .then(croppedImage => {
        this.setState({ modalOpen: false }); <-- TO HERE!
        console.log('returned from openCropper');

      })
```